# Custom Deserializer with Optional Bounds

Tags: rust, serde

I am attempting to get a [Rocket](https://crates.io/crates/rocket) + [Tracing](https://crates.io/crates/tracing) library stack working. Rocket comes packaged with [Figment](https://crates.io/crates/figment), which allows the use of [Serde](https://crates.io/crates/serde) to create application-specific configuration files.

Using this example I've created a generic de/serializer to allow my (yaml) configuration to map strings such as `log_level: "debug"` to a Tracing library log [`Level`](https://github.com/tokio-rs/tracing/blob/master/tracing-core/src/metadata.rs#L225). The below code implementing this works fine. However, if the configuration file is modified to remove the `log_level`, it breaks due to the following error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Broken!: Error { tag: Tag(Default, 5), profile: Some(Profile(Uncased { string: "default" })), metadata: Some(Metadata { name: "Rocket Config", source: None, provide_location: Some(Location { file: "src/main.rs", line: 46, col: 18 }), interpolater:  }), path: ["log_level"], kind: Message("error parsing level: expected one of \"error\", \"warn\", \"info\", \"debug\", \"trace\", or a number 1-5"), prev: None }', src/main.rs:53:47
```

This error clearly shows that `None` cannot be parsed into a `Level`. Not unexpected, but the way I usually solve this is to alter the serde struct to change the value to `Option`. And in this case I get the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::option::Option<tracing::Level>: FromStr` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:32:17
   |
12 |     pub fn deserialize<'de, D, T>(deserializer: D) -> Result<T, D::Error>
   |            ----------- required by a bound in this
...
15 |             T: std::str::FromStr,
   |                ----------------- required by this bound in `from_string::deserialize`
...
32 | #[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `FromStr` is not implemented for `std::option::Option<tracing::Level>`
```

I don't know what to do here. I don't think I quite understand why the bounds here aren't satisfied. I've used the `Option` in other configuration code, but I think there is a subtly around the type in the custom deserializer I haven't understood.

This is my `src/main.rs` file:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate rocket;

use rocket::figment::{Figment, providers::{Format, Yaml}};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use tracing::Level;

pub mod from_string {
    use serde::{de::Error as _, Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize, Serializer};

    pub fn deserialize<'de, D, T>(deserializer: D) -> Result<T, D::Error>
        where
            D: Deserializer<'de>,
            T: std::str::FromStr,
            <T as std::str::FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Display,
    {
        String::deserialize(deserializer)?
            .parse::<T>()
            .map_err(|e| D::Error::custom(format!("{}", e)))
    }

    pub fn serialize<S, T>(value: &T, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
        where
            S: Serializer,
            T: std::fmt::Display,
    {
        format!("{}", value).serialize(serializer)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Config {
    #[serde(with = "from_string")]
    pub log_level: Level,
    // This is the version that ERRORS.
    // #[serde(with = "from_string")]
    // pub log_level: Option<Level>,
    pub name: String,
}

#[get("/")]
fn index() -> &'static str {
    "Hello, world!"
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {
    let config = Figment::from(rocket::Config::default())
        .merge(Yaml::file("config.yaml").nested());

    let default_config = config.select("default");
    let cfg: Config = default_config.extract().expect("Broken!");
    println!("Config name: {:#?}", cfg.name);
    println!("Log level: {:#?}", cfg.log_level);

    rocket::custom(default_config).mount("/", routes![index])
}
```

This is my `Cargo.toml` file:

```
[package]
name = "scratch-rust"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
figment = { version = "*", features = ["env", "toml", "json", "yaml"] }
rocket = "0.5.0-rc.1"
serde="*"
tracing="*"
```

And this is an example `config.yaml` file:

```
default:
  # Remove the next line to see the 'None' error.
  log_level: "debug"
  name: "dev"
production:
  name: "production"
```

Using this code, a clean start gives this:

```
$ cargo run                                            17s nford 20:19:31
   Compiling scratch-rust v0.1.0 (/home/nford/repos/scratch-rust/tracing-serde-bridge)
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 3.41s
     Running `target/debug/scratch-rust`
Config name: "dev"
Log level: Level(
    Debug,
)
 Configured for default.
   >> address: 127.0.0.1
...more startup logs
```

I would expect to see something like this, except instead of `Level(Debug)` I'd expect:

```
Log level: None
```

Can anyone help me understand what is up with the typing bounds, and how I should go about fixing them?

(n.b. I'm only tagging this `Serde` and `Rust` because, while I have this embedded in a stack that is a bit more than that, I think this is effectively a 'how do I properly write a custom deserializer for Serde' issue.)

Comment: ok but where did you init a tracer something like that `    tracing_subscriber::fmt()
        .with_span_events(FmtSpan::NEW | FmtSpan::CLOSE)
        .with_env_filter(EnvFilter::from_default_env())
        .init();`

Comment: plus `#[launch]` is IMO bad, use `#[rocket::main]` and launch your rocket like a true kerbal engineer

Comment: also note that `RUST_LOG` will do the job

Comment: it's very hard to follow your question, please put **the code that produce the error only** avoid put comment and say "this is what trigger error" is very confusing.

Comment: you may want to use https://docs.rs/serde_with/1.10.0/serde_with/struct.DisplayFromStr.html

Comment: To answer in order: this is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), and since using the actual tracing invocation doesn't pertain I've left it out. I left the rocket stuff in since it was shorter to do so, and used the [recommended quickstart code](https://rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/guide/getting-started/) as idiomatic. I know that RUST_LOG does *a* job, but not this job (Tracing has features I need). I included all code needed to run the stack, and since there are four cases I've found, commented out code was the quickest way to elaborate what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `from_string` module as written only supports values with `T: std::str::FromStr,`. `Option` never implements the `FromStr` trait, not even if the inner value implements it.

There are multiple options how to fix that.
You can change the `from_string` module to return a `Result<Option<T>, D::Error>`. In the module, you deserialize a `Option<String>` and parse it as needed. To make the field truly optional, you might want to add `#[serde(default)]` on that field too, since the field is not automatically default if you use the with attribute.

You can also use crate which already implement this composition of custom behavior, for example using [`serde_with::DisplayFromStr`](https://docs.rs/serde_with/1.10.0/serde_with/struct.DisplayFromStr.html). You could write this instead:

```rust
#[serde_as]
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize, Serialize)]
pub struct Config {
    #[serde_as(as = "DisplayFromStr")]
    pub log_level: Level,
    
    // #[serde_as(as = "Option<DisplayFromStr>")]
    // #[serde(default)] // to make the field optional
    // pub log_level: Option<Level>,
    pub name: String,
}
```

If the `Level` struct would implement `Deserialize` you could skip the custom deserialization code. This doesn't seem to be an option for tracing though.

Comment: I think `serde_with` may be exactly what I need... I'll try that out!

Comment: I couldn't get serde_with to work, but enough surgery with the type and option seems to have worked. The serializer part was tricky, but panned out.